# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: liongenman16b1(Sqlite code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

**I am working with a exiting database .First i create a database in sqlite manager and then put it into asserts . **
[You can see my database screen shoot  and here also exits my table which i am calling DBhelper class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWbEg.png)

** Error  is  **

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: liongenman16b1(Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT street FROM  liongenman16b1 ORDER BY street,(OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1334)
                                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1268)
                                                                                           at com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Database.DBhelper.Get_Street(DBhelper.java:74)
                                                                                           at com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Fragments.Search_Frag.onCreateView(Search_Frag.java:80)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2087)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1113)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1643)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1272)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1120)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:277)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:799)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:612)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:785)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**My DBHelper Class**

```
 package com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Model.mapelmt;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Rehan Khan on 3/13/2017.
 */
public class DBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private  Context acontext;
    public static  final String     DBNAME="mapdata.sqlite";
public static final String TABLE="liongenman16b1";
    public static final String DBLOCATION="/data/data/com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app/databases/";
  private SQLiteDatabase mdatabase;
    public DBhelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, "mapdata.sqlite",null, 1);
        this.acontext=context;
    }

    public  void openDatabase(){
        String dbpath=acontext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
        if(mdatabase !=null && mdatabase.isOpen()){
            return;
        }
        File file = new File(dbpath);
        if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory())
            mdatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

      //  mdatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }
    public void closeDatabase(){
        if(mdatabase!=null){
            mdatabase.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }


public List<mapelmt> Get_Street(){


        List<mapelmt> MapelmentsArry=null;
        long result;
        String course,time,room;
         openDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        //   Toast.makeText(get, "Your BMI is " + result,  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT street FROM  " + TABLE + " ORDER BY street";
    //String query = "SELECT DISTINCT street FROM  liongenman16b1 ORDER BY street";
```

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);  //this line has error DBhelper.java:67

```
        if(cursor.moveToNext()) {


            MapelmentsArry = new ArrayList<>();
            do {


                mapelmt data = new mapelmt();
///okk here 2
                data.setStreet(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("street")));

                MapelmentsArry.add(data);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        else{
            return null;
        }
        //  Log.e("arry", String.valueOf(time_table.length));
        cursor.close();
       closeDatabase();
        return MapelmentsArry;
    }


}
```

**MY fregment class where i am calling DBhelper class .I know it is not very necessary to know you   **

```
    package com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Adapter.MapElementAdapter;
import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Database.DBhelper;
import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Model.mapelmt;
import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.R;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Search_Frag.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Search_Frag#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Search_Frag extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private ListView listView;
    MapElementAdapter adapter;
    private List<mapelmt> streetList;
    DBhelper data;
    public Search_Frag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Search_Frag.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Search_Frag newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Search_Frag fragment = new Search_Frag();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_, container, false);
        listView=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.street_list);
        data=new DBhelper(this.getContext());
        streetList=data.Get_Street();   //this error line (Search_Frag.java:80)
        if(streetList!=null)
        {
            adapter=new MapElementAdapter(this.getContext(),streetList);
            ///set Adapter
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"you couse"+inset_Course,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


            return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed code of create table.

Just add this code

```
       @Override
       public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           Log.e(TAG, "onCreate Database");     
           db.execSQL("# Add here your create table code ");
       }
```

**EDITED ANSWER**

Then you need to follow this code.

```
    public static class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            private static Context mContext;
            private static String DB_PATH = "";
            private static final String ASSETS_DATABASE_NAME = "mapdata.sqlite";

            private DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
                mContext = context;

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                    DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
                } else {
                    DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
                }

                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // If u want to Copy Database from Assets.
                            try {
                                CopyAndCreateDataBase();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }


            // If database not exists copy it from the assets
            public void CopyAndCreateDataBase() throws IOException {

                boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
                if (!mDataBaseExist) {
                    this.getReadableDatabase();
                    this.getWritableDatabase();
                    this.close();
                    try {
                        // Copy the database from assests
                        copyDataBase();

                        String mPath = DB_PATH + DBNAME;

                        Log.v(TAG, "Database created :  " + mPath);

                    } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                        throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
                    }
                }
            }


            // Check that the database exists here: /data/data/yourpackage/databases/DatabaseName
            private boolean checkDataBase() {
                File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DBNAME);
                // Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
                return dbFile.exists();
            }

            // Copy the database from assets
            private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
                InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(ASSETS_DATABASE_NAME);
                String outFileName = DB_PATH + DBNAME;
                OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
                byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int mLength;
                while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
                    mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
                }
                mOutput.flush();
                mOutput.close();
                mInput.close();
            }
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me @Dixit .Patel .i am using existing database which i put into asserts and it already have this table .then Why i need to create a table

Comment: friend i got you but my problem still there .please guide me .i copy this block and past it my dbhelper class